# How to Check if user is active before Login SQL/C#

Tags: c#, sql

Wondering how to tweek my code to first check if an account is marked active before login. I have an SQL table with column header "Active". The data type is Bool. Here is an example of table data(see image)
[image: table]

When user clicks login, the code needs to check if user is Active. If "Active" is "False", > MessageBox.Show"Account Locked"

I am a new to C#, so not sure how to go about this...Here is the login code.

```
 private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbusertype.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select User Type to continue...");
            cmbusertype.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtuserid.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your UserID...");
            txtuserid.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtpassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your password...");
            txtpassword.Focus();
            return;
        }
            try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLlocaldb; Initial Catalog = AdminAuthentication; Integrated Security = True"); ;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserRegistration where userID='" + txtuserid.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            string cmbItemValue = cmbusertype.SelectedItem.ToString();
                                             
            
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    if ((dt.Rows[i]["UserType"].ToString() == cmbItemValue) && (cmbusertype.SelectedIndex == 0)) //you can use 2 instead of usertype in that index because usertype column is in 2 index
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as " + dt.Rows[i][6]);
                        MessageBox.Show("Displaying Admin Dashboard");
                        this.Hide();
                        AdminPanel ap = new AdminPanel();
                        ap.Show();
                    }
                   

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as " + dt.Rows[i][6]);
                        MessageBox.Show("Displaying Exam Options.Good Luck!");
                        this.Hide();
                        StartTest st = new StartTest();
                        st.Show();
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and/or Password.Please try again. \nAttempts: " + attempts + "out of 3");
                txtpassword.Clear();
                attempts++;
            }

            if (attempts == 4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached maximum login attempts. Click 'Forgot Password' below to reset it.");
                btnlogin.Enabled = false;

            }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not store passwords as a plain text due to security reasons!

Comment: Also parameterize your inputs to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: You've already identified how to get values from a datarow. Why can't you just check the Active column? Something like this: `if ((bool)dt[0]["Active"] == false) { MessageBox.Show("Account Locked"); }`

Comment: Seeing SqlConnection  and TextBox code in the same method......please try to put in the most basic of layering...............see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I introduced dt.rows to your suggested solution above.